# $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}$ : problem with method I'm using

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}  \sqrt{x^2+7x}-x$

I'm having trouble finding the problem with the method I'm using:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}  \sqrt{x^2(1+\frac{7}{x})}-x$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}  x\sqrt{1+\frac{7}{x}}-x$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{7}{x}=0$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}  x\sqrt{1+0}-x$

so I get `0` for my answer. I know that graphing the function makes it clear that this is not the case but I don't see whats wrong with what I did above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* When you have that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \infty$$ and $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x) = \infty,$$ can you then conclude that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} [f(x)-g(x)] = 0?$$

(Consider $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x) = x$.)

Answer (score 1):

Idea to solve the problem using the expression's conjugate:

$$\left(\sqrt{x^2+7x}-x\right)\cdot\frac{\left(\sqrt{x^2+7x}+x\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+7x}+x\right)}=\frac{x^2+7x-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+7x}+x}=$$

$$=\frac 7{\sqrt{1+\frac7x}+1}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\frac72$$

The problems with what you did: (1) You took the limit *only of part of the expression* ($\frac7x$) while leaving the rest untouched, and this is strictily forbidden *unless you prove otherwise* in your particular case, and (2) even after this, you remain with an expression that doesn't help you solve the problem as you get " x time something minus x"... and that can be anything.